Will this work to clear the error and save the file?
When I close the user form, it's supposed to save the file the inputted information is in. I keep getting errors about "Someone else is working in". I wrote the following code to try and handle the error, but I Don't know if this is the right way to handle to error or if it's actually working? It seems like it is, but I have also gotten the error with this code in place.
Screen shot of error:
Someone else is working in 'I:\Employee Roster - DO NOT MOVE\Employee_list.xlsx' right now. Please try again later.
I have the following code in place.
Public Sub SaveEmployeeData()

'save the Employee Data


On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Workbooks("Employee_List.xlsx").Save

ErrHandler:
If InStr(Err.Description, "Someone else is working in") > 0 Then
Err.Clear
Workbooks("Employee_List.xlsx").Save
End If

End Sub

If I wrote it correctly it supposed to clear the error and try saving again.

It's important to identify the root cause of the runtime error rather than ignoring or skipping it.

Ok, I'm going to sound like an idiot, but how would one find out why it thinks there is someone else in the file. they are both opened by me. Would it be something in my code for the whole sheet.

Also, this doesn't pop up like a runtime error, normally it gives a code. This just gives the error and say wait and try again.

Pls edit your post to share a screenshot.
